# How do I Implement Custom Functionality After the Month is Changed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jQuery datepicker as an inline calendar that is used to filter the data on a page. Instead of the normal post events that it does, I used jQuery selectors to re-write the date links to be real hyperlinks.

So if I'm on page http://mysite.com/mypage, the hyperlinks will be http://mysite.com/mypage/2011-1-1, http://mysite.com/mypage/2011-1-2, etc.

So I've got a datepicker

```
$(function () {
    $('.calendar').datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: false
    });
    configureCalendarLinks();
});
```

And some code to modify the links:

```
    configureCalendarLinks = function (calendarId) {
        calendarId = calendarId || '';

        var calendarIdSelector = calendarId != '' ? '#' + calendarId + ' ' : '';
        var rootUrl = getShowRootUrl(location.href);

        $(calendarIdSelector + 'a.ui-state-default').attr('href',
            function () {
                var url = rootUrl + .getFullDate($(this).text(), calendarId));
                return url;
            });
    };

getFullDate = function (date, calendarId) {
    calendarId = calendarId || '';
    var dDate;
    if (calendarId == '')
        dDate = new Date(getDatePickerCalendarYear(), getDatePickerCalendarMonth(), date);
    else
        var dDate = new Date(getDatePickerCalendarYear(calendarId), getDatePickerCalendarMonth(calendarId), date);

    return date;
};

getDatePickerCalendarYear = function (calendarId) {
    calendarId = calendarId || '';
    var calendarIdSelector = calendarId != '' ? '#' + calendarId + ' ' : '';
    var calendarYear = $(calendarIdSelector + '.ui-datepicker-year').eq(0).text();
    return calendarYear;
};

.getDatePickerCalendarMonth = function (calendarId) {
    calendarId = calendarId || '';
    var calendarIdSelector = calendarId != '' ? '#' + calendarId + ' ' : '';
    var monthNumber = getMonthNumber($(calendarIdSelector + '.ui-datepicker-month').eq(0).text());
    return monthNumber;
};

getMonthNumber = function (monthName) {
    var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var index = $.inArray(monthName, monthNames);
    return index;
};
```

And everything worked fine until I changed the month. How do I get the code to run again when the month is changed with the datePicker? I tried using onChangeCalendar and onBeforeShow, but those fire before the calendar changes, which causes the dates to be empty.

Ideally, I'd like to re-run configureCalendarLinks in an onAfterShow() method, but there is no such thing. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

And if there's an easy, better different way to accomplish what I'm trying to do . . . that's ok, too.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are looking for?

onChangeMonthYear

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onChangeMonthYear

Comment: Unfortunately, onChangeMonthYear() fires before the new month and its cells are rendered.

Comment: If the month elements has a unique ID or class name you could bind the change event to it. $('.ui-datepicker-month').bind('change', function(){});

Comment: <td onclick="DP_jQuery_1298935772650.datepicker._selectDay('#myCalendar',9,2010, this);return false;" class=" "><a href="#" class="ui-state-default">20</a></td>

Comment: Seth, The above is what an individual element day item looks like. Is that something that can utilize bind()?

Comment: You should be able to. This may be a good case for the .delegate method. $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').delegate('.ui-state-default', 'click', function(){ console.log($(this); }); - That would console.log the element you click.

Comment: Which event id that attaching to? When the date link is clicked? The main thing that I'm trying to do isn't respond to when the link is clicked, but to modify the href of the link.

Comment: The problem is the timing of the events. DatePicker renders the days after onChangeMonth() and after the Prev and Next link click events. I can set the href, but it is overwritten a fraction of a second later. So far as I can tell, the only solution is to abandon DatePicker and go with with something more robust, such as the YUI calendar, which allows custom rendering of the date cell.